# Computing the variance of dependent random variables without using the covariance

Tags: statistics, random-variables, variance

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be independent $U(0,1)$ random variables, and set $X_1=X+Z$ and $Y_1=Y+2Z$.

The question is asking for $Var(X_1 + Y_1)$, and the provided solution uses the covariance since $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are dependent.

I was wondering if it was possible to get $Var(X_1 + Y_1)$ without using the covariance. I used these steps:
\begin{align}
Var(X_1+Y_1) &= Var(X+Z + Y + 2Z) \\
&= Var(X + Y + 3Z) \\
&= Var(X) + Var(Y) + Var(3Z) \\
&= Var(X) + Var(Y) + 9 * Var(Z) \\
&= \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{12} + 9 * \frac{1}{12} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{11}{12}}
\end{align}
The answer is the same as the provided solution's answer. Are the steps valid?

Comment: It is surely a valid computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is entirely valid.  Of course, it is consistent with using the bilinearity of covariance.

$\begin{align}
&\quad\mathsf{Var}(X_1+X_2)
\\ &=\mathsf{Var}(X_1)+\mathsf{Var}(X_2)+2\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2) 
\\ &= \mathsf{Var}(X+Z)+\mathsf{Var}(Y+2Z)+2\mathsf{Cov}(X+Z,Y+2Z)
\\ &= \mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(Z)+\mathsf{Var}(Y)+4\mathsf{Var}(Z)+2\big(\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+2\mathsf{Cov}(X,Z)+\mathsf{Cov}(Z,Y)+2\mathsf{Var}(Z)\big)
\\ &= \mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(Y)+9\mathsf{Var}(Z)+0
\end{align}$

I will say that your approach is clearer.

$\begin{align}
&\quad\mathsf{Var}(X_1+X_2)
\\ &= \mathsf{Var}(X+Z+Y+2Z)
\\ &= \mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(Y)+\mathsf{Var}(3Z)
\\ &= \mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(Y)+9\mathsf{Var}(Z)
\end{align}$

---

It comes down to $\mathsf{Var}(aZ+bZ)\\=\mathsf {Var}(aZ)+\mathsf {Var}(bZ)+2\mathsf{Cov}(aZ,bZ)\\=(a^2+2ab+b^2)\mathsf{Var}(Z)\\=(a+b)^2\mathsf{Var}(Z)\\=\mathsf {Var}((a+b)Z)$